# Excel VBA pull cell values from non-static row with empty first column

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to create a script that will help import multiple Google Analytics CSV reports into one master workbook. There are upwards of 70 reports for different websites that are generated each week and at the moment the script is set up to  loop through all the CSV files in a chosen folder and execute the import on all of them before deleting the CSVs out of the folder to clear it for next week's import. The problem I'm running into is that each CSV does not necessarily contain the same data, or in the same rows, so I can't use exact cell references to copy the values. For example:

These are all of the types of traffic available to export, plus one "totals" row at the end that never has anything in the first column

[image]

Versus this second report that only contains organic traffic data for this particular report date because no data existed for the other traffic types

[image]

So because each report might contain any number of those traffic types, the "totals" row will end up on a different line each time and I can't easily figure out how to point Excel to that row because the first cell in the row is always blank. It is also the second time a blank cell occurs in column A (there is one that happens up above to separate the data tables).

How should I approach this? Do I try to find a way to target the totals row or is there a way to have excel total up the organic, paid, direct, referral, and display traffic (if it's available) for each variable that I need to import and use that data instead?

Here is my code so far, with placeholders:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder That Contains Your Files"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        wb.Activate
    'Ensure Workbook has opened and is active before moving on to next line of code
DoEvents


Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
Dim sheet_name_result As String

strSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

Set rng1 = Workbooks("Google Analytics trends.xlsm").Worksheets("LISTS").Range("B:B").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
sheet_name_result = rng1.Offset(0, -1).Value

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox strSearch & " was found" & vbNewLine & "corresponding table is " & rng1.Offset(0, 1) & " on sheet " & sheet_name_result

        Dim table_list_object As ListObject
        Dim table_object_row As ListRow


        Set table_list_object = Workbooks("Google Analytics trends.xlsm").Worksheets(sheet_name_result).ListObjects(1)
        Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

        table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = "start date placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = "end date placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = "pageviews placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = "visitors placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = "unique visitors placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = "pages/visit placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 7).Value = "organic traffic placeholder"
        table_object_row.Range(1, 8).Value = "referral traffic placeholder"

    Else
        MsgBox strSearch & "was not found"
    End If







    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

    'Deletes all CSV files from the targeted folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill (myPath & "*.csv*")
    On Error GoTo 0


'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would be inclined to "have excel total up the organic, paid, direct, referral, and display traffic" using the SUMIF formula.

Comment: I'm a little familiar with SUMIF formulas in cell functions, not so much in VBA scripting language. Would I have to then combine it with an offset cell value to have it find the sums of the correct column? I'm just not sure of the syntax for how to write it.

Comment: The idea here is that you try some code and ask for help so make a start yourself and post back if you get stuck. Looks like you're comfortable using VBA so shouldn't be too tricky. Try recording a macro of adding a SUMIF if you don't know where to start - the syntax for the formula is pretty clear, indicate a range for comparing and another range for summing. That is only one approach though - an alternative would be the Find method.